# Nsight Graphics and RenderDoc cannot trace application

Tags: gpu, vulkan, nsight, renderdoc

I am stuck writing a Vulkan renderer. The final output I see on the screen is only the clear color, animated over time, but no geometries. Even with all possible validation turned on I dont get any errors / warnings / bestPractices / performance hints etc except for the bestPractices warning "You are using VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT when vkQueueSubmit is called". Not actually sure I use all possible validation, but I have Vulkan Configuration running and ticked all checkboxes under "VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation", after which the vkQueueSubmit hint showed up

After poking around for some hours I decided to look into using RenderDoc and I can startup the application just fine, however RenderDoc says "Connection status: Established, Api: none" and I cannot capture a frame.

Quite confused I thought I would look into using NSight Graphics just to find the same problem: I can run the application but it says "Attachable process detected. Status: No Graphics API". I read somewhere I can start the process first, then use the attach functionality to attach to the running process, which I did, unfortunately with the same outcome

I read there can be problems when not properly presenting every frame, which was the reason for me to change the clear color over time to make sure I actually present every frame, which I can confirm is the case

I am quite lost at this point, did anyone make similar experiences? Any ideas as to what I could do to get RenderDoc / NSight Graphics working properly? They both dont show anything in the logs as I guess they just assume the process does not use any graphics api and thus wont be traced.

I am also thankful for ideas about why I cannot see my geometries but I understand this is even harder to guess from your side, still some notes: I have even forced depth and stencil tests off, although the vertices should be COUNTER_CLOCKWISE I have also checked CLOCKWISE just to make sure, set the face cull mode off, checked the color write mask and rasterizerDiscard, even set the gl_Position to ignore the vertex positions and transform matrices completely and use some random values in range -1 to 1 instead, basically everything that came to my mind when I hear "only clear color, but no errors" but everything to no avail

In case it helps with anything: I am on Win11 using either RTX3070 or Intel UHD 770 both with the same outcome

**Small Update:**
Using the Vulkan Configurator I could force the VK_LAYER_RENDERDOC_capture layer on, after which when running the application I can see the overlay and after pressing F12 read that it captured a frame. However RenderDoc still cannot find a graphics api for this process and I have no idea how to access that capture

I then forced VK_LAYER_LUNARG_api_dump on and dumped it into an html which I inspected and I still cannot see anything wrong. I looked especially closely at the Pipeline and Renderpass creation calls.
This left me thinking it would be any uniform / vertex buffer content / offsets or whatever so I removed any of that, use hardcoded vertex positions and fragment outputs and still I can only see the clear color in the final image on the screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe confused me should start converting the relative viewport that I expose to absolute values using my current cameras width and height, ie giving (0,0,1920,1080) to Vulkan instead of (0,0,1,1).

Holymoly what a ride